# Derby database won't connect, or database file loading error - null pointer?

Tags: database, connection, derby

Trying to load a already created database by calling connection method from one class to another.
This is the GUIClass that calls the method to connect to db

```
public class GUIController implements Initializable {
public void loadImg() throws IOException, Exception {

        try {
            rs = dbc.Story();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            rs.next();
            fis = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
            BufferedImage imgt = null;
            try {
                imgt = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(fis);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Image failed to load.");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

And here I am connecting to the database

```
public class DBOperations {

    private Connection connection;
    private Statement statement;
    private PreparedStatement stmnt;

  public ResultSet Story() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            String query = "select vista from location where ycoordinate = ? and xcoordinate = ?";

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/.." + "/NewGame");
            stmnt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        stmnt.setInt(1, y);
        stmnt.setInt(2, x);
        rs =  stmnt.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            do {
                System.out.println("SQLState:" + e.getSQLState());
                System.out.println("Error Code:" + e.getErrorCode());
                System.out.println("Message:" + e.getMessage());
                Throwable t = e.getCause();
                while (t != null) {
                    System.out.println("Cause:" + t);
                    t = t.getCause();
                }
                e = e.getNextException();
            } while (e != null);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBOperations.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

return rs;
        }

I get a null in the end.

```
Couldn't open the story C:\Users\Konstantin\Desktop\InteractiveFictionGamePC Imported\NewGame[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@500d4560
null
```

I think it might have to do with me creating the folder NewGame just before trying to access it. I have a ready database which I'm copying and then running everything from the copy. Could it be that this is why I can't open the DB ? I'm running Java SE 8 and newest Derby.

Please help

Comment: Print out the stack trace properly with `e.printStackTrace()` everywhere  you catch an exception and show us what you get.

Comment: And to get the **complete** stack trace, here's some additional details: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain